# Lists - C (Homework)

Tags: c, list, pointers

So I'm trying to implement the following;

```
  // Destructive Abstract data type ilist

   struct ilist_ADT;
   typedef struct ilist_ADT *ilist;
   // prototype for secret implementation
   // do not rely on ilist being a pointer

   ilist iempty();
   //    returns an empty ilist

   int iempty_huh(ilist il);
   //    returns 1 (true) if il is empty
   //    returns 0 (false) if il is not empty

   int ifirst(ilist il);
   //    returns the first element in il
   //    il must not be empty

   ilist icons_destroy(int in, ilist il);
   // returns an ilist with in added as the first element of il
   // references to il cease to be valid ilists
   // the result must eventually be consumed by one of:
   //     icons_destroy, irest_destroy, idelete

   ilist irest_destroy(ilist il);
   // modifies il to remove the first element, and returns the modified ilist
   // frees the memory associated with the first element
   // references to il cease to be valid ilists
   // the result (if non-empty) must eventually be consumed by one of:
   //     icons_destroy, irest_destroy, idelete

   ilist icopy(ilist il);
   // returns a new copy of il that continues to be a valid
   // ilist with the same elements even when il is destroyed
   // the result must eventually be consumed by one of:
   //     icons_destroy, irest_destroy, idelete

   int ilength(ilist il);
   // computes the number of elements in il

   void idelete(ilist il);
   //    frees the storage for ilist
   //    all further references to il become invalid
   //    NOTE: every ilist created by icons_destroy or
   //          irest_destroy or icopy  must eventually be destroyed
   //          by being consumed by icons_destroy or
   //          irest_destroy or idelete
```

I am focusing on icons first, and i have a non-destructive icons such as:

```
ilist icons(int in, ilist il) {      
   ilist r = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_ADT));
   r->first = in;
   r->rest = il;
   r->length = 1 + ilength(il);  
   return r;

}
```

How exactly would i make this to suit the implementation? in other words how do i make it destructive?

Comment: I can't really find the question here. Can you ask a simple question, and ask the entire question here, without referring to pages elsewhere?

Comment: What is a destructive icon? Can we alter the return type?

Comment: basically we don't create anything new. I have an example of a function that doubles every number in a list of numbers http://ideone.com/YlWD4 ... and i dont think you can alter the return type

Comment: I think the `i` in `icons` is for 'integer', and the `cons` is based on LISP and its `cons` function.  The interesting requirement is the one about 'references to `il` cease to be valid'.  That seems to require the antithesis of LISP's invariant lists; you'd have to reallocate each item in `il`, but that only means that the old pointers are no longer valid - but the code retaining the old pointer won't know that it is invalid, which is tricky!

Comment: so when i add an element to a list ... I'm responsible to relocate every element of the new list? .... Will i need a helper functions? Yeaa this assignment is suppose to be one of the harder ones.

Comment: The assignment is weird; I've never seen a request for such a facility before.  I really don't want to have to go read the linked site; if the information is relevant to the question, it should really be included in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that ... updated the question. I'm working on icons_destroy first so i can get an idea for irest_destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Destructive" means that the arguments to a function (or the receiver in an oop's method) is allowed to be modified. A non-destructive function means that it does not modify its arguments but instead returns a modified **copy**. The advantage of allowing a destructive function is, that you dont have to create that copy and thus you typically need fewer mallocs (in this example, however the number is the same).

In the implementation of `icons` you provided you can see that con'ing an entry keeps the original `ilist il` a valid unmodified list!: Anyone using `ilist il` will not notice that you did anything (this only works with singly-linked lists of course).

A destructive implementation first *allows* you to modify the arguments, but it also *implies* that you are supposed to modify the arguments in a meaningful way: You should modify it such that someone who still has a reference to the original `ilist il` should **see** your modification. You can do this like so:

```
// observation: the names are not the best, i would call it destructiveICons
//   (and ->first should be called ->value)
ilist icons_destroy(int in, ilist il) {  
    ilist second = malloc(sizeof(struct ilist_ADT));
    second->length = il->length
    second->first = il->first
    second->rest = il->rest;
    il->length += 1;
    il->rest = second;
    il->first = in;
    return il;
}
```

Now someone else who holds a ref to `ilist il` will see the new-first element followed by the old-previously-first element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this implementation can be seen as destructive (though I don't really understand the significance of "destructive").
When using dynamically allocated data structures (in languages that don't collect garbage) the most important question is who's responsible for eventually releasing the data. With your `icons` implementation, the release must be done using the new handle, never using the old handle. In this sense, the old handle is no longer valid.

You can change things, so the old handle will really be unusable. You can add a filed that indicates if an `ilist` is the first in the chain, and maintain it when adding/removing elements. Then all your APIs can refuse to work if the handle given to them isn't the first.